# Why I .htaccess allow, deny order doesn't work?

Tags: security, .htaccess, hosting

```
Order Deny,Allow

Deny from all

Allow from 158.181.2.89
```

http://www.myip.ru/get_ip.php?loc= - i see my ip here

and i write it to allow myself only, but others ip to block, i can't understand why i can't allow that ip to enter??

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$array = array('192.168.0.1', '212.112.96.6');
if (!in_array($ip, $array)) {
    exit("Вход воспрещён <p>Ваш IP ".$ip."</P>");
```

i have tried this method, but it looks like many times other people have the same ip as me

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Order Deny,Allow
```

to

```
Order Allow,Deny
```

I do not understand why it is not working.

Although you can try this If you have a static IP.

set `Deny from all` to `Allow from all`. remove `Allow from 158.181.2.89`.

Add this to your `.htaccess` in `DocumentRoot`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

`F` is for forbidden. rerplace the `x`es in `xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx` by your corresponding Ip-addr.

Comment: i have changed it, but it still deny all, where can i see my real ip?, maybe in that site isnt that ip i need to put on .htaccess?, it still dont works, in my local machine works only with localhost, but in the hoster denies all:(

Comment: yeah the ip is right, but why it didn't work? =( is any other way to deny all ip, but one allow?